# Store same local storage item multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I can enter text and search for data, and then store that data, in this case a name.

```
localStorage.setItem("name", currentWeather.name);
```

Using the for loop (while on the same page), I can do multiple searches and the name data for each search is displayed on the page.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
    $("#record").append(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
    }
```

I now want to be able to store each name, so when I return to that page it still shows them all. Currently local storage is only capable of storing the latest name. I am guessing I need to create an array that I can store each search term into but not sure how to go about it. I have seen some suggest it can be done this way and other people have simply said it is not possible.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submitLocation').click(function(){

        //get value from input field
        var city = $("#city").val();

        //check not empty
        if (city !== ''){

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&units=metric" + "&APPID",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function(weatherData){
                    var currentWeather = showCurrent(weatherData);
                }
            });

        }else{
            $('#error').html('Field cannot be empty');
        }
    });
});


function showCurrent(currentWeather) {
console.log(currentWeather);
console.log(currentWeather.name);

    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

        // Store
        //saves name in local storage (for histoy list)
        localStorage.setItem("name", currentWeather.name);

        //saves name in session storage for current use
        sessionStorage.setItem("name", currentWeather.name);

        // Retrieve

        // Retrieves name from session storage 
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("name");

        // Retrieves name from local storage for history list
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("name");

        // Outputs all locations searched
        for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
        $("#record").append(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
        }

}


    else {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localStorage` only stores strings, so to store an array or object you use `JSON.stringify`.

```
var names = [ 'Philbo', 'Nipwip', 'Henk' ];
localStorage.setItem( 'names', JSON.stringify( names ) );
```

And you retrieve it with `JSON.parse`.

```
var names = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('names') );
```

Let's get silly and append a new name in a one-liner:

```
localStorage.setItem( 'names',
    JSON.stringify(
        JSON.parse(
            localStorage.getItem( 'names' ) || '[]'
        ).concat([ 'Billiam' ])
    )
)
```

For your problem:

```
var weather = [];
function showCurrent(currentWeather) {

    weather.push( currentWeather.name );

    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

        localStorage.setItem("weather", JSON.stringify( weather ) );

        ...

        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("weather") );
```

Comment: the problem with this which i have seen elsewhere is that i don't know the names. these are user defined. if I could do var names = [data] and not specify each name in the names array that would be ideal.

Comment: @Dan Yeah sure you can. Edited

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it seems as though you are setting the same key over and over, so you'd only ever have one key-value pair in your localStorage ("name"). Even if you stored the currentWeather.name value in an array, you'd still end up reassigning the same "name" key over and over.

Instead, you could make the assigned key dynamic, such as

```
localStorage.setItem(currentWeather.id, currentWeather.name);
```

Or something to that effect. I don't know what properties your currentWeather object will have. You could even simply assign the name value to both arguments of setItem.

Comment: Thats a good idea and is working with one downside, which is each time a new search is made my for loop is bringing back all data again e.g. search 1 = london, output = london. search 2 = manchester, output = london london manchester, search 3 = edinburgh, output = london london london manchester manchester edinburgh.